# How to parse a line and split it to save in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a file which contains string in each line as :

```
Format = 1A Rnti = 65535 (SI-RNTI) Format0/Format1A Differentiation Flag = 1 Localised / Distributed VRB Assignment Flag = 0 Resource Block Assignment = 0x00000000 Resource Blocks Detail = (RBstart:0, Lcrbs:1, Ndlrb:50) Modulation and Coding Scheme = 5 Harq Process Number = 16 (Broadcast HARQ Process) New Data Indicator = 0 Redundancy Version = 0 TPC Command = 0 (-1 dB)
```

I want to pick the fieldnames as key and delimit with '=' to save the corresponding value. Fieldnames are 
    Format,Rnti,Format0/Format1A Differentiation Flag,Localised / Distributed etc.
I am trying it as below :

```
with open("log.txt","r") as log:
   reader = csv.reader(log,delimiter='=')
   csv3 = open("csv3.txt","w")
   for row in reader:
      print >> csv3,row
```

But I am not able to properly split the fieldnames (key) and values.Is there a way where I can define all the key names and then store the corresponding values from the string in a dictionary ?

Comment: where's your indentation?

Comment: That file doesn't look like csv. Can you fix formatting?

Comment: Your file is not CSV (comma-separated values) formatted. In fact, it's quite a horrible format as you cannot easily discern where one fields' value ends and where one begins...

Comment: Could you pastebin an example file for us to take a look at where line endings/tabs occur to see if that might help? :)

Comment: @mx0 Sorry, it is not csv , I have processsed one csv file and saved the output in a .txt file.Now i have to process the txt file which has strings in each as above.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis Here is a sample example .https://pastebin.com/QWRvUf65. Thanks

Comment: Ahhh, well that changes things, you've made life difficult for yourself when you processed the csv file, can you post an example csv file on pastebin and what you want to get from it?

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis , Here is the sample csv file https://pastebin.com/8kAF7cJR. I need to find "DCI (Format 1A)" channel and then extract the related information ( which I have got in a text file but i further want to parse through it to output fieldnames with corresponding values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet at parsing this monstrosity (after you find and smack around a bit the author of it) is to identify all of the field names upfront and then capture the values between those fields.

The easiest way to do it is to just find each of your fields in the line and extract the value between the equal sign following it and the next found field. Something like:

```
# List all fields here (if possible in order of appearance)
# Everything not listed will end up as a part of another detected field's value
FIELD_LIST = ["Format", "Rnti", "Format0/Format1A Differentiation Flag",
              "Localised / Distributed VRB Assignment Flag", "Resource Block Assignment",
              "Resource Blocks Detail", "Modulation and Coding Scheme",
              "Harq Process Number", "New Data Indicator", "Redundancy Version",
              "TPC Command"]

# lets separate a logic to parse our ugly log in a function
def parse_ugly_log_line(log):
    field_indexes = {field: log.find(field) for field in FIELD_LIST}  # get field indexes
    field_order = sorted(field_indexes, key=field_indexes.get)  # sort indexes
    parsed_fields = {}  # store for our fields
    for i, field in enumerate(field_order):
        if field_indexes[field] == -1:  # field not found, skip
            continue
        field_start = log.find("=", field_indexes[field])  # value begins after `=`
        if field_start == -1:  # cannot find the field value, skip
            continue
        # field value ends where the next field begins:
        field_end = field_indexes[field_order[i + 1]] if i < len(field_order) - 1 else None
        if field_end and field_start > field_end:  # overlapping field value, skip
            continue
        parsed_fields[field] = log[field_start + 1:field_end].strip()  # extract the value
    return parsed_fields

# lets now open our log file and parse it line by line:
logs = []  # storage of the parsed data
with open("your_log.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        logs.append(parse_ugly_log_line(line))

# you can now access individual fields for each of the lines, e.g.:
print(logs[0]["Modulation and Coding Scheme"])  # prints: 5
print(logs[4]["Resource Block Assignment"])  # prints: 0x00000032
```

You can achieve a similar effect using regex (something like `(field1|field2|etc)\s*=(.*)(?!field1|field2|etc)` and capturing both groups to get field, value tuples) but I'm not a fan of constructed extra-long regex patterns and regex engine is not designed for such tasks anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I can iterate through the list 'logs' and get the output of all field's occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the only way for such a messy file is regexp.

```
import re 


def dicts_generator():
"""Generates dicts with data from YOUR_FILE"""

    # Defining search regexp.
    #
    # Note, that regexp here in VERBOSE MODE. It means spaces are ignored
    # and comments are alowed. Because of it I had to escape real spaces.
    # In ends i've use \s in order to make more visilble to you.
    #
    # In regexp each line is a parameter. I did not understand what exactly
    # is Rnti, so i could be wrong in exact definitions of it.


    r=re.compile(r"""

        # (?P<format> .... )  - group named 'format'
        # it will be a dict key

        Format\ =\ (?P<format>.+?)\s+   

        Rnti\ =\ (?P<rnti>.+?)\s+

        Differentiation\ Flag\ =\ (?P<differentiation_flag>.+?)\s+

        # add other parameters here

        """, re.VERBOSE)

    # Read line after line and make search in it.
    # Actually, it is OK to search whole file at once, 
    # but forme this way is more clear.        
    for line in open(YOUR_FILE, mode="tr"):
        for m in r.finditer(line):
            yield m.groupdict()


for d in dicts_generator():
    print(d)   # do whatever you want with dict 'd'.
```

It prints:

```
{'format': '1A', 'differentiation_flag': '1', 'rnti': '65535 (SI-RNTI) Format0/Format1A'}
```